# Contragredient via an involution?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

So in reading about epsilon factors of pairs for $G=GL_n(F)$ over a local nonarchimedian field $F$, the following fact was used. If $\pi$ is an irreducible smooth (complex) $G$-representation, then the contragredient $\tilde{\pi}$ can be obtained (up to isomorphism) as $g\mapsto \pi(^t g^{-1})$.

I was wondering if a similar fact held in greater generality. Roughly, for which groups is the contragredient achievable by precomposition with an involution?

If that's too broad, then simply knowing whether it's true for $GL_n(D)$ for a local central division algebra $D$ would be helpful. Note that in this case the group isn't stable under transpose so the most obvious thing doesn't work.

Apologies if this is well-known. If it is, a reference would be appreciated.